# Insert wordpress post via php fatal error

Tags: wordpress, post

When I want to use **wp_insert_post( $my_post );** function i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare create_initial_post_types() (previously
>   declared in
>   /home/izradawe/public_html/mydomain.com/wp-includes/post.php:20) in
>   /home/izradawe/public_html/mydomain.com/wp-includes/post.php on line
>   152

Can you help me with this?

Code which I using:

```
  include_once('../wp-load.php');
  include("../wp-includes/post.php");

  // Creating post
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'My post',
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_category' => 5,
     'post_type' => 'post'
  );

  // Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: What kind of file do you use to include this? Is it a theme or a plugin? anyway you're doing something wrong

Comment: I want to create separate "administrative panel" in which someone can add new post to my wordpress site, i know that is something wrong, because that i am asking for help.

Comment: So you are creating a backend completely separate from `/wp-admin`?

Comment: yes, in the complety separate backend I created a form with which admin can making a new post, and I want to use the functions wp_insert_post ($ my_post) to create a new post, but it throws the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to gain access to Wordpress' main functions, try:

```
<?php
include '../wp-blog-header.php';
$my_post = array(
  'post_title' => 'My post',
  'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_author' => 1,
  'post_category' => 5,
  'post_type' => 'post'
);
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you writing the code inside single.php or index.php or any template file inside template directory no need to include the file wp-load.php or post.php

Comment: I do not write code inside single.php or index.html, i am writing inside an separate administrative panel which i am trying to make.

Comment: Create a template page with code wp_insert_post function inside wordpress template directory and pass all your parameter to that page

Comment: I put that php page in wordpress template folder but I got the same Fatal error.

Comment: create a template page and put ur code over there here is the reference : http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Answer (score -1):

Change `include` into `include_once`.